# Implementing CHIPS cookies in ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: asp.net, chips

Chrome is starting to block 3rd party cookies soon, starting Jan 2024 with 1% of users. One use case for 3rd party cookies is embedding 3rd party content through an "iframe". It will still be supported through **Cookies Having Independent Partitioned State** (CHIPS) per Google.

https://developers.google.com/privacy-sandbox/3pcd/chips

All needed is adding the new cookie attribute called "partitioned"

```
Set-Cookie: __Host-name=value; Secure; Path=/; SameSite=None; Partitioned;
```

I'd like to be able to configure this in web.config file  (just like the SameSite change introduced a few years ago) instead of dealing with `HttpCookie` objects etc. But, I haven't seen any update in ASP.NET to support this, nor I'm aware of any guidance from Microsoft yet.

Is it because this is still considered experimental? Any guidance you are aware of from Microsoft?

Comment: I have the same question

Comment: Well, even Microsoft is not ready for this breaking change apparently. Microsoft 365 is having issues after Chrome started blocking 1% of users in Jan 24, and Microsoft suggest using Edge for now. https://support.nhs.net/2024/01/microsoft-365-alert-service-degradation-microsoft-365-suite-one-percent-of-google-chrome-users-may-experience-degraded-functionality-when-accessing-microsoft-365-services/

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this:

```
<rewrite>
<outboundRules>
    <clear/>
    <rule name="Partitioned">
        <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Set-Cookie" pattern=".*"/>
        <action type="Rewrite" value="{R:0}; Partitioned;"/>
    </rule>
</outboundRules>
```

reference: https://www.petefreitag.com/blog/samesite-cookies-iis/

Comment: I've seen the following discussion thread from Microsoft Edge forums, and someone mentions Microsoft told him to use CookieOptions.Extensions or an outbound URL rewrite like this one for now as neither .net Core nor .net Framework has support for this yet. It doesn't mention when the support will be added though. Post is from Jan 16, 2024. https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/discussions/microsoft-edge-third-party-cookie-deprecation/m-p/4002535